# Where can I find the media downloaded from whatsapp installed on a virtual device?

Tags: downloading, android-emulator, whatsapp-messenger, media-files

I installed `whatsapp` on virtual device  :

[image]

Where can I find the media downloaded from `whatsapp` ?

[image]

I searched the android directories but couldn't find the media I downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *will not* be on the Windows filesystem.

The emulator makes a `.img` file that it then mounts as the virtual SD Card.

So, to answer your question, the file is stored in the sdcard `.img` file in the avd folder.

(You *may* be able to extract it using winRAR or another unzip utility. Check the `C:\Users\<your username>\.android\avd\<avd name>\sdcard.img`)

EDIT: [This program](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html) claims to mount `.img` files. I am using Ubuntu though, so cannot test sorry.

Comment: Though I found the image file on the same path, winrar is unable to open it

Comment: @SuhailGupta You will have to use a program that mounts and/or converts .img files then. I will edit my answer very soon.

Comment: @SuhailGupta No worries!